# How to zoom in and zoom out using mouse scroll in Python using matplotlib

Tags: function, python-3.x, matplotlib, scroll, zooming

How do I make a function through which I can zoom in and zoom out into a graph on a mouse scroll event using matplotlib in Python?

I have taken help from the examples given on this community and from some other place. But this not working for me. Please look into my code and find the fault in it.

```
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

def zoom_factory(ax, step = 2.):
    def zoom_fun(event):

        cur_xlim = ax.get_xlim()
        cur_ylim = ax.get_ylim()

        xdata = event.xdata
        ydata = event.ydata

        ax = event.inaxes
        step = event.step
        if event.button == 'up':
            step = -2
        elif event.button == 'down':
            step = 2

        xdata, ydata = event.xdata, event.ydata

        if step >0:
            delx = float(cur_xlim[1] - cur_xlim[0])*step/100
            dely = float(cur_ylim[1] - cur_ylim[0])*step/100

        else:
            delx = float(cur_xlim[1] - cur_xlim[0])*step/(100-step)
            dely = float(cur_ylim[1] - cur_ylim[0])*step/(100-step)

        balx = float(xdata - cur_xlim[0])/(cur_xlim[1] - cur_xlim[0])
        baly = float(ydata - cur_ylim[0])/(cur_ylim[1] - cur_ylim[0])

        cur_xlim[0] = cur_xlim[0] - balx*delx
        cur_xlim[1] = cur_xlim[1] + (1- balx)*delx

        cur_ylim[0] = cur_ylim[1] - baly*dely
        cur_ylim[1] = cur_ylim[1] - (1- baly)*dely

        if xdata is not None:
            ax.set_xlim((cur_xlim[0], cur_xlim[1]))

        if ydata is not None:
            ax.set_ylim((cur_ylim[0], cur_ylim[1]))

        if xdata is not None or ydata is not None:
            event.canvas.draw_idle()

        plt.draw()
        fig = ax.get_figure()

        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', zoom_fun)

        return zoom_fun

def MultiXYPlot(*xy):

    fig, host = plt.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(right = 0.75)

    new = xy[0]

    x = new[0]
    y = new[1]
    x1 = new[2]
    y1 = new[3]

    p1,=host.plot(  x, y, "b-",label = "X0-Y0 plot")
    p2,=host.plot(x1, y1, "r-",label = "X1-Y1 Plot")

    zoom_factory(host, step = 2)

    host.set_xlim(0, 20)
    host.set_ylim(0, 30)
    host.set_xlabel("X0 Axis")
    host.set_ylabel("Y0 Axis")
    host.legend(loc = "upper left")
    plt.show()

x = [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15]
y = [0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 15]
x1 = [0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 15, 17]
y1 = [1, 4, 5, 8, 11, 15, 17, 19]
val = [x, y, x1, y1]
MultiXYPlot(val)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You will get better responses here if you have some code (even non-working code, so long as you _tried_).  People are glad to help you fix your code, they are less enthusiastic about doing free consulting.

Comment: and https://gist.github.com/tacaswell/3144287 which is linked to from the duplicate question.

Comment: @tcaswell - I have seen that example and based on that I have done the above coding but its not working. can you please help me in finding the bug in the above code?

Comment: What isn't working?  Where do you think the bug is?

Comment: Please re-read the linked question.  To quote:"make sure you keep a copy of f around. The call back uses a weak-ref so if you do not keep a copy of f it might be garbage collected."