# Does heatmap can be zoomed in or out via mouse scroll?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am new to using python matplotlib. I have a question about heatmap by using matplotlib.

Does heatmap can be zoomed in or out via mouse scroll?

Comment: It can, but you would need to code that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551049/matplotlib-plot-zooming-with-scroll-wheel or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878076/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-using-mouse-scroll-in-python-using-matplotlib

Comment: Thank you very much